# How to batch rename file names inbetween

Tags: batch-file, rename

This is in 3 parts leading to the 3 excellent answers below by Magoo.

Part 1;

These are example filenames;

dan williams x12c17 ford mustang
cindy stan x11c17 lexus rsx
rachel x x09c17 yamaha hayabusa 2008

---- I need to delete all the characters after `C17`

---

Part 2;

These are example filenames;

dan williams x12c01 ford mustang
cindy stan x11c17 lexus rsx
rachel x x09c90 yamaha hayabusa 2008

---- I need to delete all the characters after `C**` Where C17 can be anything between C01-C90.

---

Part 3;

Using these extended filenames;

dan williams x12c01 newyork ford mustang.xlsx
cindy stan x11c17 lexus newyork rsx.xlsx
rachel x x09c90 yamaha hayabusa 2008 newyork.xlsx

---- I need to delete everything after `C**` as in part 2 while also retaining the word `newyork` and putting it at the end of the file, and retaining the file extension.

Thoughts?

Comment: Had previously tried that, it isn't working.

Comment: @blazin8s, why is it not working for you? The solution given by Havenard should do what you are asking - what error are you getting?

Comment: @Havenard - That will not work. It will put 17 after the first c and delete everything else. So "cindy stan x11c17 lexus rsx" would become "c17"

Comment: @unclemeat - see above comment

Comment: @dbenham Actually it works perfectly for me. I tested it using the very examples you provided. I did not try it with files containing extensions though, as those were only provided on an edit.

Comment: @Havenard - no it doesn't work, but I had it backwards. It will preserve everything up through the last "c", then add 17. So a name like "x_c17_cindy" will become "x_c17_c17". See http://superuser.com/q/475874/109090 for more info.

Comment: @dbenham Well dude, I did actually try it, it worked.

Comment: @Havenard - Sorry, I didn't make myself clear. Yes it works with the examples given (additional "c" before "c17"), but it fails if there is an additional "c" in the name after "c17".

Comment: @havenard, thanks for the input.  Yes I should have mentioned I was using extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d "*c17*" ') DO (
 SET "filename=%%a"
 SET "filename=!filename:c17=:!"
 FOR /f "tokens=1delims=:" %%r IN ("!filename!") DO echo(REN "%%a" "%%rC17"
)
popd

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

Get all filenames in the directory containing `c17`, replace the `c17` with a colon, select that part before the colon and rename the original filename to that part selected+the `c17`

---

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
FOR /L %%v IN (101,1,190) DO (
 SET /a cnum=%%v
 SET "cnum=c!cnum:~-2!"
 IF EXIST "*!cnum!*" (
  FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d "*!cnum!*" ') DO (
   SET "filename=%%a"
   CALL SET "filename=%%filename:!cnum!=:%%"
   FOR /f "tokens=1delims=:" %%r IN ("!filename!") DO ECHO(REN "%%a" "%%r!cnum!"
  )
 )
)
popd

GOTO :EOF
```

Revision to allow cnumber to be varied. `cnum` is assigned `101` to `190` successively, then changed to be `c`+the last 2 digits, so `c01`..`c90`.

Thence substitute `!cnum!` throughout for `c17`, but use the `call set` construct to substitute in the filename.

---

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
FOR /L %%v IN (101,1,190) DO (
 SET /a cnum=%%v
 SET "cnum=c!cnum:~-2!"
 IF EXIST "*!cnum!*" (
  FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d "*!cnum!*" ') DO (
   SET "city="
   FOR %%n IN (newyork) DO ECHO %%a|FIND /i "%%n" >NUL & IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 SET "city=%%n"
   SET "filename=%%a"
   CALL SET "filename=%%filename:!cnum!=:%%"
   FOR /f "tokens=1delims=:" %%r IN ("!filename!") DO ECHO(REN "%%a" "%%r!cnum!!city!%%~xa"
  )
 )
)
popd

GOTO :EOF
```

will now insert `newyork` and retain extension as revised.

If you want a space before the city name, insert it after the `=` in the `set city...`

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks very much.  I was also wondering; in place of c17 the numbers actually go from c01 to c90.  I've copied the lines over and over c01 - c90 and just elongated the script and it works excellent.  While we are at it though, is it much more complicated to simplify that for better efficiency?  If it's too time consuming don't worry about it, I'm happy with this.

Comment: Brilliant and perfect.  You are awesome.  While we are at it I figure what the heck, I would like to step it up one more notch for completion.  I updated my first post, if you are interested awesome, if too time consuming, no worries.

Comment: Thank you very much Magoo.  I can work with these codes and adjust them to handle many daily renaming uses.  They work excellent.  I've edited my 1st post to more easily help accommodate others to your answers. :D

Comment: also, occasionally it spits out some funky filenames like this; Rachel Stan x12c17 newyork.xlsxe85newyork.xlsx  where the 85newyork at the end is totally random.  The 85 is always a random number as well.  without any duplicate names in the source folder.

Comment: Need to know the original filename. Is it possible that the name is being re-named?

Comment: Now that you mention it, I have a few scripts that are running before it within the same script.  So they are probably interfering.  I'll figure it out. :D

Answer (score 2):

I generally use my [JREN.BAT regluar expression rename utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081) for complex rename operations - it is much simpler than writing a custom batch script, and it performs better. JREN.BAT is a hybrid JScript/batch script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

I put all my utilities in a "c:\utils" folder, and include that folder in my PATH.

With regard to your comment to Magoo, I'm assuming that if you had a file name with c99 then you would want to rename that as well. If so, then the following one liner is all you need:

```
jren "(c\d\d).*" $1
```

Add the `/I` option if you want it to ignore case.

```
jren "(c\d\d).*" $1 /i
```

Full documentation is available by using `jren /?`. You might want to use `jren /? | more` to see the help one page at a time. But I configure my console window with a large buffer, so I can scroll up to see past output and I don't need to use MORE.

**EDIT**

I'll make one edit to handle your revised requirement. After that it is up to you to learn regular expressions and the options available to JREN.BAT.

```
jren "(.*?c\d\d).*(newyork).*(\.xlsx)$" "$1 $2$3"
```

Again, add the `/I` option to ignore case.

Comment: I will check out your program.  I have tabbed the link, it sounds like you made a nice master utility.  I am new but am having fun creating.

Comment: @blazin8s - Edited in response to revised requirement.